# New dynamic TinyMCE instance in jquery-ui tabs doesnt work on submit

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce

I have a tab-area (jquery-ui) and the content-fields are equipped with TinyMCE.
My code to create a new tab:

```
    //new tab in tab area
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
        tabTemplate: "<li id='tabLi"+tabCount+"' data-order='"+tabCount+"'><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><input type='hidden' name='tab"+tabCount+"Title' value='#{label}'></li><input type='hidden' id='tab"+tabCount+"Order' name='tab"+tabCount+"Order' value='"+tabCount+"'></li>",
        add: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).append('<textarea class="tinymceTABS" name="tab'+tabCount+'Content">still empty</textarea>');
        }
    });
    $tabs.tabs("add", "#tabs-" + tabCount, $('#newTabName').val());
```

If i want to save content of all tabs, only the content which is focused will be saved. Other contentfields only contain "still empty"-dummy.

Maybe i have to do something after creating the new tab and its tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iterating through the tabs, activating them by simulating their click event and then trying the save that instance?